# I'm trying to write a line of code at ask the user for two inputs but can't figure out how to complete this

Tags: python, split

## Why does this line of code not split the two

```
Lat1,long1 = input("Enter the Lat and Long of the source point separated by a comma eg 20,30").split()
```

Comment: where do you want to split?

Answer (score 2):

By default using `split()` will only split on a space. You are asking the user to enter two entries separated by a `,`, so you will end up getting a

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

To resolve this, you need to split on the identifier you are looking to split with. In this case it is a ',', so call `split` as `split(',')`:

```
Lat1,long1 = input("Enter the Lat and Long of the source point separated by a comma eg 20,30").split(',')
```

Demo:

```
>>> Lat1,long1 = input("Enter the Lat and Long of the source point separated by a comma eg 20,30").split(',')
Enter the Lat and Long of the source point separated by a comma eg 20,3060,80
>>> Lat1
'60'
>>> long1
'80'
```

Here is the documentation on split:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: If the user were to not split by a comma can you send back a response telling them invalid input?

Comment: You can use exception handling so that if your code can't split on `,` it can output to the user to ensure the input is "value1,value2".

Comment: great, Thank you!

Comment: @JCSenkpiel If the answer helped you with this problem, you should mark it as accepted (checkmark next to the answer) to indicate to other readers this helped solve your problem.